# Zend Framework 2 Setup default value if invalid input

Tags: php, zend-framework2

So I created a input filter (see below) but I have to test 24 fields to make sure they are all valid (only 1 listed below to keep this simple). In this case, the input is coming from an e-mail server, not a user, so I need accept the input, and not send an error back. However, I still need to check the data to ensure no one is messing with the headers / fields trying to mess everything up.

So my question is, how can I sent a default value for each input? For example blow, if the mailbox is length 0, something is wrong, so I just want to set the value to be something like 'InvalidMailbox' so I can still store this in the database,

```
public function getInputFilter()
{
    if (!$this->inputFilter) {
        $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
        $factory     = new InputFactory();

        $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name'     => 'mailbox',
            'required' => true,
            'filters'  => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StripNewLines'),
                array('name' => 'StringToLower'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name'    => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => array(
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min'      => 1,
                        'max'      => 200,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        )));

        $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
    }

    return $this->inputFilter;
}
```

Calling it...

```
$mail = new SMail();
$inputFilter = $mail->getInputFilter;
$inputFilter->setData($data);
if ($inputFilter->isValid()) {
    //echo "The form is valid\n";
} else {
    // Maybe set the default here?
    // but with 24 different fields, how can I know which one caused the error?

    //echo "The form is not valid\n";
}
```

Comment: Why store invalid data? That makes no sense to me. If you need default values, populate the form with default data when rendering the form, not after validating it.

Comment: @Sam like I said, there is no form. This is 'stdin' (E-mail comes to the server, server pipes e-mail to this script). That is why I can't just error and return... I need to clean up any bad data, then store it in the database.. Once the e-mail hits the script, if I can't validate it, it would just be lost forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, sorry that i didn't get the quest right first time. Going by the Source of the BaseInputFilter, there is a function called [`getInvalidInput()`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/InputFilter/BaseInputFilter.php#L273), so my assumption is, that you can do the following:

```
$defaultData = array(
    'elementName' => 'Default Value'
);
$returnData  = array();

if (false === $inputFilter->isValid()) {
    $falseInputs  = $inputFilter->getInvalidInput();

    foreach ($falseInputs as $input) {
        $returnData[$input->getName()] = $defaultData[$input->getName()];
    }
}

$goodInputs   = $inputFilter->getValidInput();

$finalData = array_merge($goodInputs, returnData);
```

This however is no tested code. I'm not sure if `$input->getName()` is available. You may need to adjust that part accordingly. I'm quite certain though that this should be able to get you started, hopefully ;)

Comment: I will give this a try and award you soon :-)

Comment: I'm currently working on it today :-) I will let you know (I hope) by the end of today. Thanks again Sam